# Teradata Stored Procedure Access issue

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Am trying to execute a procedure on teradata and it seems to be I don't have privileges to execute the procedure, even the SP owner isn't able to grant access to me.
Is there other way around to get access of that procedure?

Comment: Any user listed in `dbc.ChildrenV` as parent of the SP database can grant access rights.

Comment: @dnoeth The Db didn't show in the list.

Comment: That's impossible, at least `dbc` must show up as parent of this DB